# Thread wait() affects the Main thread ?

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, thread-synchronization

Consider this simple try for a multithreading example :

```
public class LetsMutexThreads {

    public static Object MUTEX = new Object();

    private static class Thread1 extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (MUTEX) 
            {
                System.out.println("I'm thread 1 , goint to take a nap...");
                try 
                {
                    MUTEX.wait();
                } 

                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("T1 : That's it , I'm done ...");
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Thread2 extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (MUTEX) 
            {
                System.out.println("Thread 2 : Let's rock N roll !");
                System.out.println("Waking up my buddy T1 ...");
                MUTEX.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Thread2 t2 = new Thread2();
        Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
        t1.run();
        t2.run();
    }

}
```

I'm trying to allow `Thread1` to go to sleep with the wait , and then let `Thread2` 
to use notify() to wake  `Thread1` , but he doesn't get a chance .

Why does the wait() of `Thread1` affects the Main Thread from executing `t2.run();` ?

Comment: Please look up the difference between run() and start()

Comment: `Thread` being a `Runnable` must be one of the stupidest things in Java APIs.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: My threads do not implement Runnable .

Comment: I advise you to check again :) It is impossible. BTW it's not your fault, but JDK's.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Please enlighten me  .

Comment: `package java.lang; public class Thread implements Runnable { ... }`.

Answer (score 4):

You must not attempt to start a thread using the run() method. It does not actually create a new thread, it runs the code in the current thread. Use thread.start() instead in order to have your code executed in a separate (new) thread

Comment: Right idea, but "should" makes it sound like the caller has a choice when in fact, there is no such choice.  The _only_ way to start a thread is to call `t.start()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have updated my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
Thread2 t2 = new Thread2();
Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
t1.run();
t2.run();
```

Change it to this:

```
Thread2 t2 = new Thread2();
Thread1 t1 = new Thread1();
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Comment: Your first snippet is not _wrong_  Not in and of itself.  It's only wrong if it fails to do what the programmer intended it to do.  Your answer doesn't say anything about the programmer's intent.  Your answer doesn't say _why_ the first example is wrong or why the second one is right.  All you're doing here is throwing the noob a fish when you could be teaching him _how_ to fish.

Comment: Okay. Is it ever right to create a Thread object (instead of a Runnable) and then call run()? I can't think of any situation where it would be desirable. I hope the reader sees the difference in the two code snippets and looks up the documentation on the two methods to understand the rest.

Comment: "Right" as in good design?  I can't imagine how a call to `t.run()` could ever improve the _design_ of a program, but I can imagine it as part of a cheap, sleazy hack that fixes a bug.  I've seen worse.  Heh!  I've probably _committed_ worse, and in commercial products too.  As for your hope, don't worry about it.  Antonis_wrx already gave the noob the information that he needs.